# Extending TypeScript Function with additional arguments

Tags: typescript, function

For fun and practice, I'm writing some code to solve puzzles. For this to work, I have implemented rules which is essentially a function that returns a boolean. If all the rules return true, the puzzle is solved. This is pretty straightforward.

My problem enters when you need to have multiple types of rules for a puzzle. Take sudokus for example; you need rules for the whole grid, rules that apply to each of the 9 boxes, and rules for each individual cell.

The way I went to implement this was to have a base function that took no parameters but was bound to a class. Then I wanted to create a new function type that extended the base type and allowed an additional parameter.

This introduced some problems. First of all, I needed to add an additional parameter to the `check` method that would be passed to the condition which TypeScript didn't like so I've had to add `...args: any` to the base `check` method signature. Secondly, I'm unable to instantiate an instance of `RuleFunctionB`.

I've included example code as well as a link to the TypeScript playground below. If anyone could enlighten me and tell me where I'm going wrong, that would be greatly appreciated.

```js
class A {} // doesn't matter for this
class B {}

interface RuleFunction extends Function {
    (this: A): boolean
}

class Rule {
    private readonly ruleName: string
    protected readonly condition: RuleFunction
    
    constructor(ruleName: string, condition: RuleFunction) {
        this.ruleName = ruleName
        this.condition = condition
    }
    
    check(a: A, ...args: any): boolean {
        // the ...args parameter was required to allow
        // overriding the method in RuleB
        return this.condition.call(a)
    }
}

interface RuleFunctionB extends RuleFunction {
    (this: A, other: B): boolean
}

class RuleB extends Rule {
    constructor(ruleName: string, condition: RuleFunctionB) {
        super(ruleName, condition)
    }
    
    check(a: A, other: B): boolean {
        return this.condition.call(a, other)
    }
}

const RULES = [
    // TS2345: Argument of type '(this: A, b: B) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RuleFunctionB'.
    new RuleB('Example rule', b => !!'example return')
]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8C+0D0roBMD2BTCAdgOQAu0AtmCSbgE7QBm29JAFgJYQBQokMAQoiRcu7AjVoMwwXNABKAVxC4AYgoLAS7bAWi4AHjQKYYajVp2IuASAAUbTgC44ASmcAjbNmVgCXYTzgUPJKsgg2AA607ABuVLK0uGA4BCAAntC0oQByYOS4zhAk0QQA5pG02DSauJiZSSnp0MA6mOwWBM6Kymaa2n7WNi0ERVmazLZZyrn5hcVipQA0za3t-V2hvR0uVtbWDhAAdFO4M7IAvJk5ebg2+xxHw20d0JdPazo2woPWwKy4wAA1rYwM5YMtDpCwLRShBnL40m5oJ5vEldOE9uhoGxZJDDtDYdAItCbhJoAB3SD1ACOCnYiTqJGw0DAIBA2HJdyx2BidGibTK2P+FFwbGwdTEIWU-DuiRIClougOh3eHRVrJAIJcX38IjEEikMilqnUfR0ggMRhMxq2-V29geYOWVX+tGc-CRKJ8fgCvGC3VwFsMuGMMADu2GowU41ok2us2gowWy1V6xtpo6Ht21ggCgidDj0xuKdW2x1Pz+AOBoLgzpxbugHo8Xm92blCqVDxVpf66rZILrru11mEvp0RXkAFUADIAUQAyhtlABtAC6r2gy5sWIAKvOAEwAZgALABWMEwhT5cTQbAMbFpfPQIgOpy15HunbnAB8yJbaKIaBOGgAgqhZKB2FKAgwHcZRsWZYlaFJOhb3vEhH1kIgA1tc0iEOGwCFwcljX4WwiFnfQ8giOCTiIZZ3FeX8AEImKIAwqJo0UOyIbVVy4IA)

Comment: You'll need to define `RuleFunction` as `(this: A, ...args: any[]): boolean` https://tsplay.dev/Wy4axm And there's no point in `interface RuleFunctionB extends RuleFunction` if `RuleB` must receive the parameter

Comment: How were you planning on having the code which iterates over the `RULES` array know what arguments it needs to pass to the `check` functions?

Comment: @ccarton `RULES.filter(rule => rule instanceof RuleB)`

Answer (score 0):

`RuleFunctionB` extends `RuleFunction`. This means that it also inherits the declaration for for the function from `RuleFunction`.

This means that any object of type `RuleFunctionB` **must** be callable in any place where and an object of type `RuleFunction` could be called.

This means that the second parameter is actually optional.

Update your array init to this and it should work:

```
const RULES: Rule[] = [
    new RuleB('Example rule', (b?) => !!'example return')
]
```

Note: I only made **b** optional.